# Can not open mysql connection

Tags: c#, mysql

My SQL Connection is as follows :

```
MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=mysql1.000webhost.com;DATABASE=a7232830_UsrAuth;UID=a7232830_UsrDet;PASSWORD=P@u!301094;");
```

while debugging it stops at

```
mcon.Open();
```

and says

```
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

even after I had created a firewall permission allowing connections made by this process.

Comment: I don't know if it's the actual password, but if so I'd recommend you to remove the password from your example code.

Comment: Apparently the permissions are not good enough. The server is unreachable.

Comment: Are you sure that you have network access to that server. Have you tried to [ping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737478(v=ws.10).aspx) it?

Comment: You can try to workaround the problem by connecting from another client, for example MySQL Workbench: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/. If it works, then the issue is in your C# code/MySQL DLL. If it doesn't works you have the issue in yout MySQL server.

Comment: After removing password also the exception persists.

Comment: If I remember correctly, 000webhosting is using cPanel. Have you enabled your IP in the MySQL Remote Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the website 000webhost.com you can't directly connect to MySQL (http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27).

If you want to get data from MySQL by using free account you should communicate via web service, e.g. you can use NuSOAP library to create web service.

Comment: I've changed from 000webhost.com to another host and when I tried to connect it shows Host '59.92.101.253' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server